Automate the process of creation of teams and to configure permissions for Github repositories
I'm trying to automate the process of creating teams and configuring permissions for GitHub repositories. Specifically, I need to create a new team within my GitHub organization, add members to the team, and set repository permissions for the team.
I found some manual approaches but I want to accomplish this through automation code.

I use the GitHub CLI for these types of tasks:
I use it for syncing repository settings across repositories, adding branch controls consistently, managing self-hosted runners, etc.
GitHub CLI Manual
Some functionality has specific 'gh' commands, but other times I just use 'gh api' to interact with the GitHub API. Here is an example of enabling auto merge for a repository using the GitHub CLI in PowerShell:
gh api `
    --method PATCH `
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" `
    /repos/$repositoryOwner/$repository `
    -F allow_auto_merge=true `

